# Common SQL Server database on LAN

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I want to do system to control other machines in LAN. I need here a database, but it should be one database for all computers. I hope it's possible to have installed SQL Server only on chosen machine and connect from others to him over LAN?

Or make db on each comp and synchronise fom time to time with main db?

Comment: I am confused... Is this a joke? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**YES OF COURSE!!**

That's the whole point of a database server....

You install a SQL Server version on your server machine, and any number of clients in your LAN can connect to it, read data from it, store data on it.....

Since you're in a LAN environment (inside a company), I would recommend using Windows authentication (the user names people are logged into Windows with) as your security mechanism. You can easily configure certain Windows users (or Windows groups) to have access to your SQL Server (and others are locked out).

Once you have set up your database server, your client apps can connect to it using a connection string something like this:

```
server=(server-name);database=(your database name);integrated Security=SSPI;
```

Comment: Indeed. The clue's in the name, really.